# Unable to rwrite request spec using rspec for devise login for rails-api application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-api, devise-jwt

We use Rails 6.1 **API** application with `devise` and `devise-jwt`. I tried to write a feature spec using RSpec for `sign_in` method but could not write. I have the following in my **rails_helper.rb**

```
 config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :feature
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
```

and the spec under `spec/requests/users/sessions_controller_spec.rb` is

```
 context 'When logging in' do
    before do
      request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      sign_in user
    end

    it 'returns a token' do
      expect(response.headers['Authorization']).to be_present
    end

    it 'returns 200' do
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
```

But still not able to succeed any idea?

Comment: _But still not able to succeed_ What didn't work as expected, any errors?

Comment: what is the error you get when you run your specs?

Comment: ` Failure/Error: request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/users/sessions_controller_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
`